# wso2 dss - securing web service with http basic over https

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server

I was wondering if it's possible to secure the web service by using http basic authentication over https.
I've seen that dss offers ways to secure the service, but all of them seem to be wss methods making use of SOAP headers.

For my clients, it would be easier if I could protect the service simply by http basic authentication.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following [sample](http://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB470/Enabling+HTTP+Basic+Authentication+through+a+Proxy+Server) which shows how you can enable basic auth to a proxy service.

Comment: I only have WSO2 DSS installed no ESB. Does your example mean I should have a reverse proxy in front of it? In that case any reverse proxy would do the job, apache for example.